# compare two values of one struct and getting extra cells in UITableView swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My code which contains a tableview where I am trying to compare two values from one struct it's giving me total number of array while its even printing the compared data which contains even extra cell that is not required. I want to compare cellID and cellID2 values if they match then it should print only those cells !!! Can someone help me with this error[image: My Simulator screenshot]

```
import UIKit

struct One {
    let cellID: String
    let name: String
    let lastName: String
    let cellID2: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var arrayOne = [One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "1"), One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "1"), One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "2"), One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "1"), One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "2"), One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "1")]

    @IBOutlet weak var compareTableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOne.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CompareTableViewCell") as! CompareTableViewCell
        let arrayID = arrayOne[indexPath.row]
        if arrayID.cellID == arrayID.cellID2{
            cell.lblOne.text = arrayID.cellID
            cell.lblTwo.text = arrayID.cellID2
            cell.lblThree.text = arrayID.lastName
            cell.lblFour.text = arrayID.name
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach isn't right. First of all, you should filter out the elements from the array that you don't want to show in the table view. Then you will use that filtered array for your data source. If you follow this, you won't have to write the weird condition in your `cellForRowAt:..` function.

Comment: @nayem can you help me with filtering the array

Comment: I want to compare cellID and cellID2 values if they match then it should print only those cells !!!

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @nayem yes I am trying that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should filter out the elements from the array that you don't want to show in the table view. Then you will use that filtered array for your data source. You won't have to write the weird condition in your `cellForRowAt:..` function.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let arrayOne = [One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "1"), One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "1"), One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "2"), One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "1"), One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "2"), One(cellID: "1", name: "hello", lastName: "hello last", cellID2: "1")]

    var filteredArray = [One]()

    @IBOutlet weak var compareTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Here you apply your filter
        filteredArray = arrayOne.filter { $0.cellID == $0.cellID2 }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CompareTableViewCell") as! CompareTableViewCell
        let arrayID = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        // Feed your cell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 4 values that match my array but its even printing the one that does not match

Comment: Okay. Don't edit answers like this. It should be a comment instead. You missed the part inside the `tableView(:cellForRowAt:)`. You have to use the `filteredArray` here.

Comment: ok i used and its working successfully but if i want to compare an array value with a variable how am i supposed to do that????

Comment: if let userID = companyDefaultValue.string(forKey: "user_type_id"){
            print("user type ID=\(userID)")
        } I want to compare this value with my One of my struct value

Comment: Well, that is another question. You should look for something similar or ask a new question separately.

Comment: I tried looking out for an answer but I did'nt get any yet can you help me with this???

Comment: Have you asked the question? If not, then how should I know what's your purpose and what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to compare a variable value with a struct value and if it matches it should print the values that match

Comment: I don't get it what you are looking for. You want to filter your array (of structs) by matching with another variable, right? The word **compare** is ambiguous and not within the context. It's best to ask another question, you describe your need with sample input and output.

Comment: ok I'll ask another question Thanks though!!! I hope you'd help me with my next question

Comment: I have posted another question can you help me with that

Comment: hello can you help me with my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501640/compare-value-from-two-struct-in-swift